# How can i solve "No project found" error when installing react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and i am taking my first course on openclassrooms on react. 
The instructor is using the command
 `yarn global add create-react-app`
 to setup but when i run the commdand i get the error below

```
Usage Error: No project found in /E:/Web Dev/React/react-project
```

i have tried to use the command below that is provided in the react documentation but i stil get the same error

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

How can i solve the problem i have looked up on the react documentation but still cannot find the solution.

Comment: Did you try `npx`? [Like `npx create-react-app my-app`](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Comment: Do you have `yarn` installed globally? Try normal node, `npm i -g create-react-app` to install `create-react-app` globally in your node modules. *Note: this may require elevated privileges* Actually, do what @Jai suggests [create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview)

Comment: @Jai  That is what i used `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: When i have just created what what @Jai has suggested above but i get the error below                                       ` 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`

Comment: @Dijiflex you need to install the dependencies with either `yarn` or `npm i`. run yarn for better.

Comment: @Jai that is what i did and   i have just  realized the node modules folder does not exits . And also when i run the command in my desktop everything works well and i can see the node modules folder, and if run the same command in my local disk E i get the same error.    so am wondering why it does not work on the other drive because that is where i store all my projects

Comment: Below is the details error when i run `yarn start`     `e:\Web Dev\React\Udemy\Projects\monsters-rolodex\monsters-rolodex\.pnp.js:30177      
    throw firstError;
    ^

Error: Couldn't find a suitable Node resolution for the specified unqualified path   

Source path: /e:/Web
Rejected resolution: /e:/Web
Rejected resolution: /e:/Web.js
Rejected resolution: /e:/Web.json
Rejected resolution: /e:/Web.node
Rejected resolution: /e:/Web.mjs`

Comment: just `yarn`. It will load all the dependencies and will create node_modules directory.

Comment: it brings this error `No project found in /E:/Web Dev/React/Udemy/Projects/monsters-rolodex `

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and solved it as follows:

1. Uninstall yarn from npm using `npm uninstall -g yarn`
2. Install Yarn from [Installation - Yarn Classic](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable)
3. Restart PowerShell / CMD

Before performing the above steps `yarn --version` printed `2.0.0-rc.27` on my machine. Now it prints `1.22.4`.

Having Yarn 2.x globally installed is discouraged accourding to [Installation - Yarn 2.x](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#global-install).